# Replace Ajax.ActionLink output to use Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

Is there an easy way of replacing the generated output of Helper function Ajax.ActionLink to use Jquery instead of MS ?

Or must i do all the job in a custom Extension?
Someone must have done this

EDIT:

I think i'm looking at replacing the MicrosoftMVCAjax.js with something done with JQuery. Something called JQueryMVCAjax perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

Start by replacing `Ajax.ActionLink` with `Html.ActionLink` in your view and give it an unique id so that you could attach handlers to it in javascript:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("link text", "action", "controller", null, 
    new { id = "mylink" }) %>
```

And then attach a click handler in a separate js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        // send ajax request
        $.get(this.href, function(result) {
            // The ajax request succeeded => do something with the results
            alert(result);
        });
        // make sure you cancel the default redirect action
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you just want to replace the contents of some div with the result of the AJAX request you could use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#resultDiv').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```